WorkerRpcFailed - Tasks are failing in Apache Druid with this exception
I am using Apache Druid for data storage and now I am trying to fetch a datasource which is around 7Gb of size to local storage using the druid extern function like
INSERT INTO
  EXTERN(
    local(exportPath => 'exportLocation/query1')
  )
AS CSV
SELECT *
FROM test

I tried this in my dev environment and it worked, but while trying in Prod env this seems not working and throwing below exception:
"status": {
      "id": "query-6c555efd-4fa5-4235-852f-2b932ed3eb60",
      "groupId": "query-6c555efd-4fa5-4235-852f-2b932ed3eb60",
      "type": "query_controller",
      "createdTime": "2024-10-07T10:58:43.454Z",
      "queueInsertionTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "statusCode": "FAILED",
      "status": "FAILED",
      "runnerStatusCode": "WAITING",
      "duration": 56763,
      "location": {
        "host": "--------",
        "port": -------,
        "tlsPort": -
      },
      "dataSource": "__query_select",
      "errorMsg": "WorkerRpcFailed: RPC call to task failed unrecoverably: [query-6c555efd-4fa5-4235-852f-2b932ed3eb60-..."
}

Is there any configuration setting that was missing in prod is what I want to know. Also can anyone explain why this kind of exception occurs?
I am trying to compare the runtime.properties file from both envs, Is there any other way we could get a complete datasource as a CSV (or multiple CSV files by partition)?
